# Loop until entry matches a predetermined value

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to have a user try a guessing game. The program should loop until the user guesses right.
How can I compare the values? Right now its going through the else part every time, even when the user guesses right.
Here is the code;

```
import sys
from random import randint

secret_number = randint(0, 100)
num_guesses = 0
guess = 0


while guess != secret_number:
    guess = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if (guess < secret_number):
        print "Your guess is too low. Please try again."

    else:
        print "Your guess is too high. Please try again."
    num_guesses = num_guesses + 1

print "Thank you, you guessed right"

print guess
```

Comment: As well as changing the type of the user's guess to an int, you need to check if the guess is correct between inputting it and telling the user it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the string that `raw_input` returns into an integer using `int`, so the comparison operator works the way you expect it to:

```
guess = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 2):

raw_input will return string, you compare string with int and nothing works

also you will never guess the number:
your code hav 2 options: too low or too high

also you never compare tries with max tries (try to fix that by yourself)

corrected version:

```
import sys
from random import randint

secret_number = randint(0, 100)
num_guesses = 0
guess = 0


while guess != secret_number:
    guess = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if (int(guess) < secret_number):
        print "Your guess is too low. Please try again."

    elif (int(guess) > secret_number) :
        print "Your guess is too high. Please try again."
    else:
        print "Thank you, you guessed right"
        break

num_guesses = num_guesses + 1



print guess
```